# How to save multiple form at single submit in PHP laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, laravel

I've a form which can be saved to database multiple times depending upon number of entries in to it. To be precise, I have 4 input fields and after filling all the fields I click on **Add** button. Upon clicking on Add button, I'm creating an entry in a table row inside `<form>` tag like,

```
<form>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td> <input type="hidden" name="a[]" value="xyz" /> xyz</td>
   <td> <input type="hidden" name="b[]" value="123" /> 123</td>
   <td> <input type="hidden" name="c[]" value="456" /> 456</td>
   <td> <input type="hidden" name="d[]" value="abc" /> abc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> <input type="hidden" name="a[]" value="xyz" /> xyz</td>
   <td> <input type="hidden" name="b[]" value="123" /> 123</td>
   <td> <input type="hidden" name="c[]" value="456" /> 456</td>
   <td> <input type="hidden" name="d[]" value="abc" /> abc</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</form>
```

Now I want to save each row of the table into database as a row. I'm unable to understand how to do that. I'm getting the data in controller using `dd($a = $request->input('a'));` for a single field as,

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "xyz"
  1 => "xyz"
]
```

I'm using this to save it into DB using Laravel,

```
$save=Model::Create(array(
        'a'=>$request->input('a'),
        'b'=>$request->input('b'),
        'c'=>$request->input('c'),
        'd'=>$request->input('d')
));
```

I'm getting error,

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in /var/www/html/quoting/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php on line 681 and defined

How can I save it into the database using the Laravel command.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change name for all inputs

```
<form>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td> <input type="hidden" name="myform[a][0]" value="xyz" /> xyz</td>
   <td> <input type="hidden" name="myform[b][0]" value="123" /> 123</td>
   <td> <input type="hidden" name="myform[c][0]" value="456" /> 456</td>
   <td> <input type="hidden" name="myform[d][0]" value="abc" /> abc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> <input type="hidden" name="myform[a][1]" value="xyz" /> xyz</td>
   <td> <input type="hidden" name="myform[b][1]" value="123" /> 123</td>
   <td> <input type="hidden" name="myform[c][1]" value="456" /> 456</td>
   <td> <input type="hidden" name="myform[d][1]" value="abc" /> abc</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</form>
```

Then in your controller first `dd($request->myform)` and check you are getting values properly

if you want to store multidimensional array then you have ot use insert not create

```
$save=Model::insert(multdimensionl array here);
```

Comment: I think you can leave the numbers out of the last pair of brackets in each input name, they will be automatically added.

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
$input = $request->all();

foreach($request->a as $key => $value) {
    Model::Create(array(
        'a' => $value,
        'b' => $input['b'][$key],
        'c' => $input['c'][$key],
        'd' => $input['d'][$key],
    ));
}
```